# Raspberry Pi not connecting to hidden SSID WIFI

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, debian-wheezy, raspbian

I have a problem with edimax ew-7811un on my Raspberry Pi.
I am trying to connect to a hidden SSID, let's call it "hiddenssid" with a WPA2 Personal password "hiddenpassword". 
I can see wifi dongle in iwconfig.
I created a PSK version of my password:

`$ wpa_passphrase "<Your Wifi SSID>" "<Your Wifi PASSWORD>"`

here is my `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
   wpa-scan-ssid 1
   wpa-ap-scan 1
   wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
   wpa-proto RSN WPA
   wpa-pairwise CCMP TKIP
   wpa-group CCMP TKIP
   wpa-ssid "hiddenssid"
   wpa-psk pskpassword

iface default inet dhcp
```

Here is what I get when i type `sudo ifup --force wlan0`:

```
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.2
Copyright 2004-2011 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wlan0/74:da:somethingsomething
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/74:da:somethingsomething
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 12
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 18
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Here is `iwconfig`:

```
wlan0     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.437 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated
          Sensitivity:0/0
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Try this tutorial for connecting a RPi: http://weworkweplay.com/play/automatically-connect-a-raspberry-pi-to-a-wifi-network/

Comment: Unfortunately, after `sudo ifup --force wlan0`, I get:
`ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWENCODEEXT]: Invalid argument
ioctl[SIOCSIWAP]: Operation not permitted
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant daemon failed to start
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
(...)DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 13
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.`